# How do I use a sub-string of a field?

Tags: 8, database

How do I convert `SELECT title , SUBSTRING(title,13,4) as num FROM node_field_data ORDER BY ABS(num)` to the format for Drupal 8?

I tried this code.

```
 $query = $db->select('node_field_data', 'nfd')
  ->extend('\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
  ->extend('\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender');
  $query->limit('50');
  $query->fields('nfd',array('title',substring(title,13,4) as num,'changed','nid'));
 ->orderBy('num', 'ASC')
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add an expression with [`SelectInterface::addExpression`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21SelectInterface.php/function/SelectInterface%3A%3AaddExpression/8.2.x):

```
$query = $db->select('node_field_data', 'nfd')
  ->fields('nfd', ['title'])
  ->extend(\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender::class)
  ->extend(\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender::class);

$expr_alias = $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(title, 13, 4)', 'num');

$query->orderBy($expr_alias, 'ASC')->limit('50');
```